# Why doesn't the Angel Watch building work as per the in game description?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

In the second mission of the tutorial campaign, one of the secondary missions is to build a unique building in your starting town.  I chose the **Angel Watch** building, which has the following right-click description:

> Fills the Guardian Angel faction ability gauge to rank 1 at the start of each combat.

After building the Angel Watch, I fought many battles before the end of the mission, and I only saw the faction ability gauge start at rank 1 twice.

Is there some other requirement that must be met before the building activates?  If so, what is it?

Comment: It could be once per turn?

Comment: @RavenDreamer - I don't think so, as it definitely did not happen the first battle after I built the building, since I was watching for it.  After the first few battles I stopped paying close attention, but I know there were a couple of battles where the gauge did start filled to the first rank.

Comment: I support this observation. It doesn't seem to work at all as it should be.

Comment: Maybe it only applies to combat in the town?

Comment: @DavidFullerton - I'm actually wondering if it may only work within the town's area of control, but I haven't been able to fully test that theory yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug.

Angel Watch seems to only function within the domain of the town it's been built in. It's not apparent whether the ability itself, or just the tooltip, are wrong.

Source: Ubisoft's forum has a [pretty extensive buglist.](http://forums.ubi.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/5861060878/m/3141070459)